# Copy product data from one store to another

Tags: product, import, magento-1.5

Due to some changes in website I need to copy product data (name, description, price, etc.) from one store, to another. The setup is simple. There is a product which has some default values and then for each store some changes are applied (usually translated default values). Now, one store must use the same values as another one for all of the products. What's the best way to do that?

Currently I have shell script that gets product collections from both stores (so I can check if product is present in both stores). But I'm a little stuck on the copying part. Do I go through every product in collection of the first store, and go through all of its data with foreach and set this data to product in the 2nd store? There must be a cleaner way for that.

Comment: Did you tried via csv export/import method, when you have the entire csv i guess that can help you out

Comment: I'm not sure how that would work. Product already exists in both stores, i just need to transfer data like name, description etc from one store to another without removing or adding new products

Comment: I suggest you to give a try on this, I have shard a link in my answer you can follow that

Comment: I will give this a go, but given that custom importing/exporting was used for this project I'm not entirely sure that this will work. It's the reason it was decided to use shell script

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution I used in the end was pretty simple. I gathered necessary attribute changes via `array_diff_assoc` and used the result in `Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_action')->updateAttributes()`

**EDIT**:

The reason I opted out of direct DB query is quite simple, it's unsafe and I don't have much control over it. Using standard magento tools was also out of question since there were some customizations made to products that might result in incorrect data transfer. Checking all of the products to make sure it went well and no attributes are lost is out of the question.

So the solution I chose was shell script that would offer me some flexibility and control over entire process. What I did was really simple. I've gathered product collections for both stores in question. Compared them, logged the products that were not in one of the stores. I iterated through the rest of the products, getting the difference in attributes via `array_diff_assoc` and passing it to `Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_action')->updateAttributes()` along with `product_id` and `store_id`

Comment: since you accepted your own answer, could you elaborate a bit on what you did so as others see why you accepted your answer over the others which looked quite right?

Comment: Hi @Darvex, could you please post the shell script. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm afraid the script is long lost @thismethod

Answer (score 3):

All you have to do is change the ID’s defined at the start.

```
# DEFINE
SET @to_store := 6;      # the store_id of the recipient store

SET @from_store := 2;    # the store_id of the donor store

/*********************************************************
 * catalog_product_entity                                *
 *********************************************************/

# PROCESS datetime VALUES
DELETE FROM catalog_product_entity_datetime
WHERE store_id = @to_store;
INSERT INTO catalog_product_entity_datetime (
    store_id,
    entity_type_id,
    attribute_id,
    entity_id,
    value
) SELECT
    @to_store,
    entity_type_id,
    attribute_id,
    entity_id,
    value
FROM catalog_product_entity_datetime
WHERE store_id = @from_store;


# PROCESS decimal VALUES
DELETE FROM catalog_product_entity_decimal
WHERE store_id = @to_store;
INSERT INTO catalog_product_entity_decimal (
    store_id,
    entity_type_id,
    attribute_id,
    entity_id,
    value
) SELECT
    @to_store,
    entity_type_id,
    attribute_id,
    entity_id,
    value
FROM catalog_product_entity_decimal
WHERE store_id = @from_store;


# PROCESS gallery VALUES
DELETE FROM catalog_product_entity_gallery
WHERE store_id = @to_store;
INSERT INTO catalog_product_entity_gallery (
    store_id,
    entity_type_id,
    attribute_id,
    entity_id,
    position,
    value
) SELECT
    @to_store,
    entity_type_id,
    attribute_id,
    entity_id,
    position,
    value
FROM catalog_product_entity_gallery
WHERE store_id = @from_store;

# PROCESS int VALUES
DELETE FROM catalog_product_entity_int
WHERE store_id = @to_store;
INSERT INTO catalog_product_entity_int (
    store_id,
    entity_type_id,
    attribute_id,
    entity_id,
    value
) SELECT
    @to_store,
    entity_type_id,
    attribute_id,
    entity_id,
    value
FROM catalog_product_entity_int
WHERE store_id = @from_store;

# PROCESS text VALUES
DELETE FROM catalog_product_entity_text
WHERE store_id = @to_store;
INSERT INTO catalog_product_entity_text (
    store_id,
    entity_type_id,
    attribute_id,
    entity_id,
    value
) SELECT
    @to_store,
    entity_type_id,
    attribute_id,
    entity_id,
    value
FROM catalog_product_entity_text
WHERE store_id = @from_store;

# PROCESS varchar VALUES
DELETE FROM catalog_product_entity_varchar
WHERE store_id = @to_store;
INSERT INTO catalog_product_entity_varchar (
    store_id,
    entity_type_id,
    attribute_id,
    entity_id,
    value
) SELECT
    @to_store,
    entity_type_id,
    attribute_id,
    entity_id,
    value
FROM catalog_product_entity_varchar
WHERE store_id = @from_store;


/*********************************************************
 * catalog_product_entity_media_gallery                  *
 *********************************************************/

# PROCESS value VALUES
DELETE FROM catalog_product_entity_media_gallery_value
WHERE store_id = @to_store;
INSERT INTO catalog_product_entity_media_gallery_value (
    store_id,
    value_id,
    label,
    position,
    disabled
) SELECT
    @to_store,
    value_id,
    label,
    position,
    disabled
FROM catalog_product_entity_media_gallery_value
WHERE store_id = @from_store;

# IM UP TO HERE

/*********************************************************
 * catalog_product_option                                *
 *********************************************************/

# PROCESS price VALUES
DELETE FROM catalog_product_option_price
WHERE store_id = @to_store;
INSERT INTO catalog_product_option_price (
    store_id,
    option_id,
    price,
    price_type
) SELECT
    @to_store,
    option_id,
    price,
    price_type
FROM catalog_product_option_price
WHERE store_id = @from_store;

# PROCESS title VALUES
DELETE FROM catalog_product_option_title
WHERE store_id = @to_store;
INSERT INTO catalog_product_option_title (
    store_id,
    option_id,
    title
) SELECT
    @to_store,
    option_id,
    title
FROM catalog_product_option_title
WHERE store_id = @from_store;

# PROCESS type_price VALUES
DELETE FROM catalog_product_option_type_price
WHERE store_id = @to_store;
INSERT INTO catalog_product_option_type_price (
    store_id,
    option_type_id,
    price,
    price_type
) SELECT
    @to_store,
    option_type_id,
    price,
    price_type
FROM catalog_product_option_type_price
WHERE store_id = @from_store;

# PROCESS type_title VALUES
DELETE FROM catalog_product_option_type_title
WHERE store_id = @to_store;
INSERT INTO catalog_product_option_type_title (
    store_id,
    option_type_id,
    title
) SELECT
    @to_store,
    option_type_id,
    title
FROM catalog_product_option_type_title
WHERE store_id = @from_store;

/*********************************************************
 * catalog_product_super_attribute                       *
 *********************************************************/

# PROCESS label VALUES
DELETE FROM catalog_product_super_attribute_label
WHERE store_id = @to_store;
INSERT INTO catalog_product_super_attribute_label (
    store_id,
    product_super_attribute_id,
    use_default,
    value
) SELECT
    @to_store,
    product_super_attribute_id,
    use_default,
    value
FROM catalog_product_super_attribute_label
WHERE store_id = @from_store;

/*********************************************************
 * catalog_product_bundle_option                         *
 *********************************************************/

# PROCESS value VALUES
DELETE FROM catalog_product_bundle_option_value
WHERE store_id = @to_store;
INSERT INTO catalog_product_bundle_option_value (
    store_id,
    option_id,
    title
) SELECT
    @to_store,
    option_id,
    title
FROM catalog_product_bundle_option_value
WHERE store_id = @from_store;
```

Answer (score 1):

Go to

> System > Import/Export > Export
>
> Select Products from drop down > Check on attributes you want to
> EXCLUDE.

I suggest to give it a try I think this method can be very fast for you can update the csv way faster then doing it manually

[This](http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/tutorial-using-magentos-import-export-profiles) Magento Tool Can be helpful to you.